# Android ListVIew Swipe to dismiss

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I need some help.I'm using this [EnhanceListView](https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView) for swipe to dismiss in my alertDialog but the swipe is not working. Does the swipe to dismiss doesn't work on alertdialog? or Am i missing something.? I tried setting the directions but still not working.

here is my code

```
public void viewDataList() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_opendata, null);

        lv = (EnhancedListView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.data_list);

        TextView emptyText = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        lv.setEmptyView(emptyText);
        DisplayDataAdapter adapter = displayData();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setDismissCallback(new OnDismissCallback() {
            @Override
            public Undoable onDismiss(EnhancedListView arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });

        lv.setSwipingLayout(R.id.swiping_layout);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Close",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();
    }
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <de.timroes.android.listview.EnhancedListView
        android:id="@+id/data_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#C0C0C0"
        android:minHeight="30dp" >
    </de.timroes.android.listview.EnhancedListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="No Data"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my List Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiping_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:background="#F8f8f8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/datalist_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F8f8f8"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't see you setting anywhere `lv.enableSwipeToDismiss();`

also, you may want to add stuff like:

```
lv.setUndoStyle(EnhancedListView.UndoStyle.MULTILEVEL_POPUP);
lv.setSwipeDirection(EnhancedListView.SwipeDirection.BOTH);
```